# Integrating $\csc 5x$

Tags: integration

What is $\displaystyle\int \csc 5x\, dx$ ?

Why am I supposed to multiply $\dfrac{1}{5}$ and times by $5$?

How does the answer end up as $\dfrac{-1}{5} \ln |\csc 5x + \cot 5x| + C$ ?

Comment: use the substitution $u=5x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int csc(5x)dx=\frac{1}{5}\int csc(u)du $ by using u=5x substitution.
Now
$$
\frac{1}{5}\int csc(u)du=\frac{1}{5}\int\frac{csc(u)(csc(u)+cot(u))}{csc(u)+cot(u)}\\
=-\frac{1}{5}\int\frac{-csc^2(u)-csc(u)cot(u)}{csc(u)+cot(u)}\\
=-\frac{1}{5}ln|csc(u)+cot(u)|+C\\
=-\frac{1}{5}ln|csc(5x)+cot(5x)|+C
$$
ln is used since the numerator is the differentiation of denominator.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \csc 5x dx=\int \frac{\csc 5x(\csc5x+\cot5x)}{\csc5x+\cot5x}dx
\\ \int \csc 5x dx=\int \frac{(\csc^25x+\csc5x\cot5x)}{\csc5x+\cot5x}dx$$